# Disable elements in responsible design

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, css

I have created a responsive blogger template. Everything is working fine but I want to make it better. My website contains some widgets which I want to disable in phone and tablet view. My responsive design works perfect with mobile and tablets but the problem is it loads all the widgets and then hide them. I have used `display: none` method for hiding this unwanted widgets and it is working but it increases the page loading time. I really don't need this widgets in mobile view. I just want to completely disable this widgets, so my web page load at greater speed.

Comment: `widgets` ? what kinda? important to know. you can `disable` those via `jquery`

Comment: @jiff widgets like a fixed or floating social media bar, sidebar etc.

Comment: I mean, they are `plugins` or you made it for your self? you can `remove` those with something like this `$('#mySocial').remove()` but how to detect? you can detect `resolution size` or `mobile agent`

Comment: @jiff have used the this method  `@media (max-width: --px)` to detect. Here you can see it. [link](http://www.responsinator.com/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.secondgf.com%2F) http://www.responsinator.com/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.secondgf.com%2F

Comment: this is `media` for detect resolution, but wee need remove `elements` via `jquery`. you can't remove elements with `CSS`. I going to write a answer for you, hope it solve your problem.

Comment: @jiff You are right, i haven't disabled them, I have hided them using `display: none` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can detect `window` resolution size with:

```
var width = $(window).width();
var element = $('.widget-content');

if ((width <= 1024)) {
$(element).remove();
}
```

or detect `mobile agent` with:

```
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
$('.widget-content').remove();
}
```

Comment: glad to help @Akshay